# Replacing missing values by the most frequent one based on the values of other two variables

Tags: r

I am working with `R` and have a dataset which is comprised of three variables: e.g. `A`, `B` and `C`. Variable `C` has some `NA` observations which I wish to replace by the most frequent value of `C` with the same `A` and `B` quantities. As an example, in the following dataset:

```
   A B  C
1  1 2  0
2  2 1  1
3  1 1  1
4  3 1  1
5  1 2  0
6  1 2  0
7  2 3  0
8  1 2  1
9  3 3  0
10 1 2 NA
```

Here, I would like to replace `NA` by `0` since it is the most frequent value of `C` when `A=1` and `B=2`.
I know it can be done if I write a function to obtain frequencies and the corresponding values, however, I was wondering if there are less complicated ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(A, B) %>%
    add_count(C) %>%
    mutate(C = if_else(is.na(C), C[which.max(n)], C)) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 x 3
       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     2     0
 2     2     1     1
 3     1     1     1
 4     3     1     1
 5     1     2     0
 6     1     2     0
 7     2     3     0
 8     1     2     1
 9     3     3     0
10     1     2     0
```

Explanation: Group entries by `A` and `B`, add a count for every `C`, replace `NA` values in `C` with the most frequent non-`NA` value in `C`, and tidy-up the `tibble` to reproduce the expected output.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   A B  C
1  1 2  0
2  2 1  1
3  1 1  1
4  3 1  1
5  1 2  0
6  1 2  0
7  2 3  0
8  1 2  1
9  3 3  0
10 1 2 NA
", header = T)
```

Comment: But in case `NA` is the most frequent value in the grouped data, it returns `NA`, right?

Answer (score 0):

### base R

(sorry for a very long line)

```
unsplit(lapply(split(df, list(df$A, df$B), drop=TRUE), function(.) {.$C[is.na(.$C)] <- names(which.max(table(.$C)));.}), interaction(df$A, df$B, drop = TRUE))

# output
   A B C
1  1 2 0
2  2 1 1
3  1 1 1
4  3 1 1
5  1 2 0
6  1 2 0
7  2 3 0
8  1 2 1
9  3 3 0
10 1 2 0
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there's duplicated rows in A and B.

Comment: What do you mean? Rows 1, 5 and 6 are identical (`duplicated`) in the OP's sample data, and the code above works.